# Spring Integration: Allocate Space when sending file to FTP

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I have the following problem:

We are sending files to a FTP. We hadn't been having problems since we were sending files of size < 5 MB. If the file size is greater than 5 MB, then we get an abend (an abnormal end), getting [this error](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.cs3cod0/ftp451-06.htm) :

In order to "solve" this issue, we should allocate space before sending the file to the FTP, doing something like this:

```
QUOTE SITE BLOCKSIZE=0 LRECL=256 WRAP UNIT=DISK RECFM=VB PRI=50 SEC=50 CYL
```

Currently I'm using `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` along with a `FileTransferringMessageHandler` in order to send files to the FTP (obviously it works well unless the file is > 5 MB).

**My question is**: Is there a way to solve this issue using Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't tried that, but look. You can extend `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` and override its `postProcessClientAfterConnect()`.

Then you can try to perform

```
FtpClient.sendSiteCommand("QUOTE");
FtpClient.sendSiteCommand("SITE");
FtpClient.sendSiteCommand("BLOCKSIZE=0");
FtpClient.sendSiteCommand("LRECL=256");
```

and so on until the end of your command.

You can check [here](http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/java-code-to-preallocate-space-for-destination-mainframe-file-using-ftp/) also.